# How to make SonarJS show ESLint issues?

Tags: eslint, sonarjs

I am trying to import ESLint issues to SonarQube by the following:
`eslint -f json -o report.json .`
And then running sonar-scanner with key `-Dsonar.eslint.reportPaths=report.json`.

However, SonarQube analysis reports only issues for rules provided by the repository SonarAnalyzer. How can I make SonarQube to report ESLint issues as well?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First create the Report:

eslint src/ --format json --output-file eslintreport.json

Then change your sonar configurations,

Here a good Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kghYozZD6UQ